# Highlight TOC on scrolling. Works fine on jquery 1.10.1 but not 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery, and I just want to make my blog looks better.  So I decided to make the links in TOC just move when the page scroll, after searching for a while, I find a way finally.

**Code**:

```
$(function() {    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            $(":header").each(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

It works well when jquery is 1.10.1, but when it comes to 3.0.0(my blog framework uses 3.0.0), it doesn't work any more.

Can anybody help me out?  I'm stuck for a night.

Here's my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/selfboot/y7uL0nw9/)

Comment: Add relevant code here at SO, rather than circumventing the warning. if you can add fiddle so can __snippet__

Comment: According to [specs](https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) it should work. Also a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp14onfa/)

Comment: But why my code in fiddle doesn't work in jquery 3.0.0?

Comment: @selfboot because **Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3**

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay so how can I fix it?  I'm not familiar with jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: @selfboot Use lower version, as I am mostly using *jQuery ver 2.2.4* on my *Bootstrap* based projects.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay In fact I use the hexo theme  [maupassant-hexo](https://github.com/tufu9441/maupassant-hexo) in my blog. I'm afraid something unexpected happened when change jquery to version 2.2.4.

Comment: I tried you fiddle and changed to jQuery 3.0.0 and changed this line  $('.nav a[href="#'+ id +'"]').addClass('active'); by adding " " to href. http://jsfiddle.net/y7uL0nw9/3/ it is working now

Comment: @Zorken17 Yeah, It works!  You can write it to as answer and let me accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried you fiddle and changed to jQuery 3.0.0 and changed this line 
`$('.nav a[href="#'+ id +'"]').addClass('active');`

by adding " " to href. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7uL0nw9/3) it is working now